# Image of restricted flow map

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, reference-request

Let $M$ be a (smooth) compact manifold and $X$ be a vector field on $M$. Let $\psi:\mathbb{R}\times M\to M$ be the flow associated to $X$. We know that:

- for each $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $\psi|_{\{t\}\times\,M}$ is a diffeomorphism,
- for each $p\in M$ such that $X_p\neq 0$, $\psi|_{\mathbb{R}\times\{p\}}$ is an immersion.

Are there other kown results which gives you information about the flow for other submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}\times M$ (such as $\mathbb{R}\times S$ where $S$ is a submanifold of $M$)? Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One such result is the *flowout theorem*, which is Theorem 9.20 in my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (2nd ed.). It says, in part, that if $S$ is a $k$-dimensional embedded submanifold of $M$ and $X$ is nowhere tangent to $S$, then the restriction of $\psi$ to $\mathbb R\times S$ is an immersion, and its image is an immersed $(k+1)$-dimensional submanifold near $S$.

Comment: That's perfect! I didn't know there was a second edition, I have just read which topics you decided to add and I am very happy that you deal with transversality: do you discuss it with genericity statements? In any case thank you for your books, they are all greatly helpful!

Comment: @Balloon: I don't discuss genericity per se, but I do prove the following **Parametric Transversality Theorem**: _Suppose $N$ and $M$ are smooth manifolds, $X\subseteq M$ is an embedded submanifold, and $\{F_s:s\in S\}$ is a smooth family of maps from $N$ to $M$.  If the map $F\colon N\times S\to M$ is 
transverse to $X,$ then for almost every $s\in S,$ the map $F_s\colon N\to M$
is transverse to $X$._

Comment: @Baloon: And you're welcome!